# Koma scrbook seems not to include BCOR

Tags: latex

The proof copies of a book laid out with KOMA scrbook show that the inner margins are too narrow. I had BCOR set to 10mm and want to increase them, but my experiments with BCOR set to 20mm show that the layout is the same independent what BCOR value I set. Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=      
    128.5mm:198.4mm, %(5,06" x 7,91")  %ziel
    BCOR=20mm,
    twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true,
    %   draft=true, 
    DIV=9,  %ziel kleines buch 
    fontsize=12pt,
 }

\usepackage[german]{babel}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,axes,cross,pdftex,center]{crop}



\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
        \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter

\part{ Philosophie}
some text 
\lipsum
\lipsum 

\end{document}
```

What is wrong?

My real question is: how can I just move the text area on both pages to the outside (i.e. making the gutter wider) without changing the text area size (and thus preserve line breaks)?

Answer (score 3):

I found a hint in some other questions answered before and the problem was caused by the interaction between the `KOMA script` and the `geometry` package. Using the `geometry` package recalculates the page layout and overwrites the one calculated by `scrbook` including the `BCOR` value. This can be avoided when adding the option `pass` to `geometry` as in

```
`\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`.
```

In general the interaction between the layout calculated by KOMAscript and other package can lead to surprises. The discussion in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182821/div-and-bcor-setting-in-koma-best-practices/183839 is very useful.